# Could SE include a citation tool?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

To help everyone provide proper references to support their answers, could SE include a tool in the editor that builds citations in a standard format? Perhaps Harvard referencing? Could also include radio button options to allow users to declare any affiliation with the source.

Comment: Yes it does - and twelve years later it never happened. What a shame. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem. But perhaps next time use the search function before proposing a new feature to see if it was proposed before.

Comment: @Luuklag I did and could not see it. Thanks for the poke in the right direction.

Comment: There is a "Cite" button on *[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)*. [Example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/666796/if-the-probability-of-a-point-photon-hitting-another-point-electron-is-zero) (probably not a very good one). Is that related or not? Can you address this in your question (even if it is totally unrelated)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)